# How to use pyserial expect on a string from serial console, then send a charater

Tags: python

I'm a new to python, hoping someone knows something about the issue I have. I want to control a device using serial console. A command will be sent to reboot the device, while the device is rebooting, a string is printed. I want to catch the string and then send a character "h" which will abort the reboot. Code looks like this

```
#! /bin/env python

import serial
import sys
import pexpect
from time import sleep
from serial import SerialException

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port="/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff=0

try:
    ser.open()
except:
    sys.exit ("Error opening port")

print "Serial port opened"
ser.write('rebootnow\r')

temp = ser.expect('press h now to abort reboot..')

if i == 0:
    print ('Gotcha, pressing h')
    ser.sendline('h')
    print ('Reboot aborted')
else:
    print ('Ouch, got nothing')
    time.sleep(1)
ser.close()

exit()
```

When I run the code, I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'expect'
```

at line

```
temp = ser.expect('press h now to abort reboot..')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This thread is quite old, but I hope my answer can still be useful to you.

The expect methods are from pexpect, not from pyserial.  You should do something like:

```
temp = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(ser)
temp.expect("message")
```

Basically, from temp onwards you should call methods on the temp object, not on the serial object. This includes the sendline() call, later on.